# Association between mongo and postgres model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I have two database in one app

1. Postgres
2. MongoDB

Except one model, all models are in `Postgres`
Model name `Message` is in `MongoDB` as following

1. `message.rb` - MongoDB

   ```
   class Message
     include Mongoid::Document

     field :content,         type: String
     field :user_id,         type: Integer
   end
   ```
2. `user.rb` - Postgres

   ```
   class User < ApplicationRecord
   end
   ```

Now I want to associate `user` model with `message` model, to perform eagerloading.

If I write `belongs_to :user`, and then perform `Message.last.user` then following error will raise

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `_association' for []:Array)
```

Is there anyway to fix this issue?

Answer (score 3):

You can't really make cross-database associations like that. But, depending on how much of the association you need, it might be easy to fake it:

```
class Message
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :content,         type: String
  field :user_id,         type: Integer

  def user
    User.find(user_id)
  end
end
```

If you're not sure about the validity of your `user_id`s then:

```
def user
  User.find_by(id: user_id)
end
```

might work better but you'll have to be prepared for `nil`s to come out of `some_message.user`. You'll probably want to add some validations on `user_id` to make sure it really is the `id` of a `User`.

Of course, this chicanery won't help you propagate user deletions into MongoDB or support `has_many :messages` in `User`. You'd have to do those by hand as well but an `after_destroy` (or `around_destroy`) hook and a couple simple hand-written methods (and a solid test suite) can fill in those gaps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, as I have already done this, but this is not answer of my question, I want to define relationship between two model.

Comment: You can't build a cross-database relationship unless you do it by hand.